# Why does one need to compactify space in a Euclidean CFT?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, compactification

It is often claimed [1] that in Euclidean CFT's on $\mathbb{R}^d$ one needs to first compactify space to the sphere $S^d$, as $\mathbb{R}^d$ is not invariant under conformal transformations. I cannot see in practice what contradictions would arise if one remained on $\mathbb{R}^d$. For example in $d=2$, I see no contradiction with correlators obeying

$$A_n(z_{i})=\Bigg(\prod_i (c z_i+d)^{h_i}(\bar{c}\bar{z}_i+\bar{d})^{\bar{h}_i}\Bigg)A_n(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}) \tag{1}$$

Can one reach a contradiction when interpreting $(1)$ for $z=x+iy,\bar{z}=x-iy$ variables where $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$?

To make my question precise: can someone construct a mathematical contradiction that arises when one constructs a Euclidean CFT on a non compact space such as $\mathbb{R}^d$?

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00098 see bottom of page 8, the starting paragraph of section 2.1

Comment: Is it a contradiction to restrict your CFT to a patch and still demand that (1) always holds? Sure. Take $z = c = -b = -d = 1$, $a = 0$ and $d = -1$. Then the LHS involves points in the patch and the RHS does not.

Comment: When constructing a CFT on a non-compact space you don't get a discrete spectrum of momenta. The momenta can then take arbitrarily small values, which leads to infrared divergences.

Comment: Infrared divergences in what? Momenta, unlike scaling dimensions, do take arbitrarily small values in CFT.

Comment: In scattering amplitudes: this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/57970/radial-quantization-and-infrared-divergences?rq=1 explains more than I can fit in here.

Comment: @sondre CFTs on non-compact space make sense, they just don't have S-matrices. But they don't have them on compact spaces either.

Comment: @Luke one doesn't have to compactify, but then one needs to specify a conformally-invariant boundary condition at infinity. But that is conformally-equivalent to compactifying via a Weyl transformation.